# how to write sql query to compare today's price with yesterday's

Tags: sql

Given a price table, write a SQL query to find the  Ids with higher price compared to its previous (yesterday's) dates

table price

```
|    Id   |    Date    |  price |
|       1 | 2015-01-01 |     20 |
|       2 | 2015-01-02 |     30 |
|       3 | 2015-01-03 |     40 |
```

Question : I tried to use `to_days` to express the concept of "yesterday" but my sql developer cannot recognize this function

```
select p1.id
from  price p1, price p2
WHERE p1.price > p2.price
AND   TO_days(p1.date)-TO_days(p2.date)=1;
```

I also tried to use `subdate()` function to compare the price, but again I got  invalid identifier error, what is wrong?

```
select p1.id 
from  price p1, price p2
WHERE p1.price > p2.price
AND   subdate(p1.date, 1)= p1.date;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.  I notice that you are getting errors on the MySQL functions, so perhaps you are using something else.

Comment: It may depends on the DB but diff of 2 dates should give a result in days. try `select date '2017-06-05' - date '2017-06-04'`